# Viewer Browser Disabled in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm currently using R Markdown, and am hoping to check my work as I go. But my viewer pane doesn't seem to be working? I also tried switching it to Window Pane, but that doesn't allow me to preview my work either. What may be going on?

Here is an image of what I'm seeing on my end:

[image]

Comment: You're making a reference to a function `corstars()` that you haven't defined in the document.

Comment: Phil no no, I'm just interested in seeing the Viewing Pane in general, not just for that command. I have a whole doc of command, but cannot view them on the right.

Comment: I guess, to better explain, how can I preview my doc?

Comment: You can't until you fixed the error you're running into.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks Phil. How do I fix that? And why could I not see the Viewing Pane from the beginning?

Comment: Where does `corstars()` come from? Did you create it? Is it from a package? When you knit a markdown document, it does so in its own environment, which means that everything you refer to within the document must be created or loaded via a package in that document.

Comment: It came from this page: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/elegant-correlation-table-using-xtable-r-package. I just took it out of my code though to clarify my question, and I'll add my screenshot to the question.

Comment: Add `library(xtable)` to your .Rmd document, and then click on "Knit" again.

Comment: But it is already there, should I delete and re-add it? Thanks Phil

Comment: It's okay, I don't really need the Viewer Panel, I think I'll let it be, but thanks!